# Javascript hoisting process with immediately invoked functions: Why doesn't this declared function run before function expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Code:**

```
var funcExpression = function(){
  alert("function expression");  
}();

(function declarFunc(){
  alert("declared func");  
})();
```

The result is the function Expression is run first resulting in the alert *`"function expression"`* and the declared function is run second *`"declared func"`*.

I know that during the hoisting process, declared functions are hoisted up entirely within their container and loaded into memory.  Function expressions, however are not hoisted: they stay in the same place and are not loaded into memory until runtime(though the variable that points to the function expression is hoisted up and set to `Undefined`.  *(Please correct me if I have this concept wrong)*

Since, the declared function is hoisted up above the function expression assignment, I would expect thus that the declared function is executed first: resulting in the alert *`"declared func"`* and then the function expression is executed afterwards: resulting in the second alert of  *`"function expression"`*.

However: it doesn't do what I expect. Thus, it seems like it has something to do with the immediate invocations of both the functions.  Maybe the immediate invocations stay in the same order?  Maybe after the hoisting process the code really looks like this:

```
var funcExpression = Undefined;

(function declarFunc(){
  alert("declared func");  
})

funcExpression = function(){
  alert("function expression");  
}();

(); // this executes declarFunc.  Maybe declarFunc is hoisted up 
    // but the invoking part stays in the same place?
```

Comment: Because in the first snippet both are function expressions, and expressions are executed in the order they appear.

Comment: @Teemu oh, so the parenthesis around the function declaration transforms it into a function expression?  Also, did I describe the hoisting load process and resulting code order correct?

Comment: Yep, parenthesis does that, but nothing is hoisted, they are just expressions. More information at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: You could test if it was hoisted by simply console.logging `declarFunc` at the top, you'll get undefined. If you unwrap it the console.log will then give you the function.

Comment: Well, I actually created [a test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1L2y2od7/1/)  to play with for a while ago, just forgot to post the link.

Comment: Must-read: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution after feedback and additional research**

The answer is that BOTH of those functions are function expressions:

Code:

```
var funcExpression = function(){
  alert("function expression");  
}();

(function declarFunc(){
  alert("declared func");  
})();
```

so `declareFunc()` looks like a declared function, but since it is wrapped in parenthesis like that, it transforms it into a *named* function expression.  The parenthesis following immediately evokes this function expression.

I was having trouble showing what the code looks like after the hoisting process because `(function declarFunc(){...})()` transforms into a **named function expression** due to those wrapping parenthesis.  What this means is that *outside of this named functions scope*, we have no way to call it.

Example: If after these functions I did `declarFunc()` it will return with the error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: declarFunc.`

If we did want to make it possible to run this function expression then we would want to assign the function expression to a variable:

```
var foo = function declarFunc(){
  alert("declared func");  
};
```

**Note:** If we look at the console we will see that `console.log(foo())` will return `undefined`, but the actions of the function will still take place.  Just know that if no `return` statement is specified, then it implicitly returns `undefined`.

And now we can call on that function as many times as we would like with `foo().`

Comment: That's not quite right. A named function expression doesn't create a variable in the current scope (except in old versions of Internet Explorer thanks to a bug which also causes them to memory leak). The only `declarFunc` variable is scoped *inside* that function.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your comment.  Would you mind showing what it would look like then after the hoisting process?  I want to make sure I understand what you mean before I change my solution above.

Comment: FWIW, even if it was a function declaration, only the **definition** would be hoisted. Anything that is done with the function would still take place where it is located in the source.

Comment: `If we did want to make it possible to run this function expression then we would want to assign the function expression to a variable` This is correct, but the code you pasted after it does not do this - it assigns the returned value of the expression as a variable, and in this case, the return is _undefined_. You'd either need to `return declarFunc;` or separate the `var foo` from the assignment so you can do `(foo = function declarFunc() {})();`

Comment: An easy way to think _"Is this function an expression or declaration?"_ is to think _"Is `function` being used as an operator or statement?"_, which you can rephrase as _"If I replaced the function with a `var foo`, would I get an error?"_

Comment: @PaulS.: I don't think a function is ever an operator. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @FelixKling I think of the `function` keyword in an expression in the same way as the `new`, `void` or `typeof` keywords are operators -- maybe it's just me. But the URL for it on MDN does call it [**/Operators/function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). This is in contrast with a keyword which can only ever be a statement, e.g. `var`, `const`

Comment: @PaulS.: An operator also needs an operand. `function` is definitely not an operator (what would be it's operand?). It's really just a keyword. I don't think it's correct to say that a keyword dictates whether something is a statement or not. It's rather the other way round: A specific statement or expression might consist of specific keywords.